# Is ssh tunneling to remote server Php admin secure?

Tags: tls, ssh

I have not been able to find an answer online so I thought I would ask here. I have setup an Amazon Lightsail instance to act as a development platform for my website. I have setup SSH for accessing administrative tools such as PHPMyAdmin. Would this be sufficent in terms of being able to securly access PHPMYAdmin and upload files or should I be using SSL aswell?

Comment: You should *always* use HTTPS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Would this be sufficent in terms of being able to securly access
>   PHPMYAdmin and upload files or should I be using SSL aswell?

I am guessing you are talking about Secure socket tunneling to run the localhost on the remote server as given [here](https://docs.bitnami.com/bch/faq/get-started/access-phpmyadmin/).

The secure socket tunneling protocol already does SSL/TLS provides transport-level security with key negotiation, encryption and traffic integrity checking.[wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Socket_Tunneling_Protocol)

That should be sufficient.

Comment: So that would also count when i use the website (Sending and recieving data from the db) through the localhost?

Comment: You mean remote server localhost right?yes